# constexpr recursive function using if constexpr or not

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++17

Using gcc (HEAD 7.0.0 201612) I was surprised to discover that this works:

```
constexpr long value(const char *definition)
{
    if (definition && *definition)
    {
        return *definition + value(definition + 1);
    }

    return *definition;
}

int main()
{
    long l{};
    std::cin >> l;

    switch (l)
    {
        case value("AAAA"): f1(); break;
        case value("BBBB"): f2(); break;
        default: error();         break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The literal strings `"AAAA"` and `"BBBB"` were treated as compile-time values and the calls to `value` function yields the values `260` and `264` used directly in the `switch` context; I should admit that I was expecting the compiler complain about "*strings are no constant expressions*". So I moved to the next step and tried to add a `if constexpr` to the algorithm:

```
constexpr long value(const char *definition)
{
    if constexpr (definition && *definition)
    {
        return *definition + value(definition + 1);
    }

    return *definition;
}
```

But by adding the `if constexpr` the code no longer compiles:

> ```
> In function 'constexpr long int value(const char*)':
>  error: 'definition' is not a constant expression
>      if constexpr (definition && *definition)
>                                             ^
> ```

So it seems that the `definition` pointer itself is not evaluable at compile time in the `if constexpr` context but using traditional `if` the whole function is evaluable at compile time.

Why is this happening?

Comment: which compiler and version are you using exactly?

Comment: @m.s. sorry forgot to say: gcc HEAD 7.0.0 201612

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's happening for the same reason you can't do this:

```
constexpr auto func(const int foo)
{
  return std::array<int, foo>{};
}
```

`foo` may *or may not* be a constant expression, depending on how you call `func`. But what you put into a template parameter *must* be a constant expression. Therefore, this code fails to compile.

The same goes for your `value` function. What you put into `if constexpr` *must* be a constant expression, just like with template arguments. So you cannot put something there which may or may not be a constant expression, like parameters to `constexpr` functions.

Comment: But the call to `value` without `if constexpr` is a constant expression! If it wasn't I wouldn't be able to use it in the `case` clause, isn't it?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster: Yes, but not every call to `value` *must* provide a constant expression. `constexpr` functions do not *have* to be given constant expression parameters, but they still have to work if they are not.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster You're right, yet that doesn't contradict this answer. Given `const char *foo = "Hello";`, `value(foo)` would be valid too, just would not be a constant expression. And for such calls, `if constexpr` couldn't work.

Comment: Sorry for my silliness but I still don't get it. The instructions inside the `if` should be constant expression, if not, `value` will fail when used in `case` clause (`case value(std::string("AAAA").c_str())` will fail). So I still don't get why it fails in `if constexpr` when it seems to be compile-time evaluable.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster: There's no implicit "if this isn't a constant expression" part to the syntax. That's not what `if constexpr` is for. An expression either is a constant expression or it is not. This is a static property of an expression, based on the nature of the expression's component parts. `1 + 2` is a constant expression. `a + b` is only a constant expression if both `a` and `b` are declared `constexpr`. Parameters to `constexpr` functions are not declared `constexpr` and thus are not constant expressions.

Comment: @NicolBolas There's *explicit* "If this isn't a constant expression", because if it isn't it will fail to compile in contexts where compile-time values are mandatory. So if `if (whatever)` compiles in a compile-time (constant expression) context I would expect that `if constexpr (whatever)` will compile in the same context. Do you know some article where I can read more about `if constexpr`?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster: This is not a template function. Whether it compiles or not is not *context dependent*. Either the function compiles or it does not; this *cannot* be dependent on the nature of the argument it is passed. You cannot write a `constexpr` function that does something different if the argument is not a constant expression. A `constexpr` function *must* be able to take arguments which are not constant expressions, and they must result in the same computation for the same input.